# Problems sharing document on IOS when the user doesn't have an email account on the device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a problem when I try to share a pdf document using **UIActivityViewController** via email.

When the user has configured his email sharing works well, the document it appears attached, but when the user doesn't have an email account previously configured it prompts the user to chose an email provider, if I configure the email account the new email it appears but without the document attached. If I try again with the email configured it works well.

I have test it on iOS 9 and 10 and it gives me the same problem.

This is my code on Objective C:

```
NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@", items[0][@"source"]];

NSURLRequest *urlRequestToLoad = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL                                                                                                                                     URLWithString:file] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSArray *sharingItems = @[items[0][@"filename"], [urlRequestToLoad URL]];

UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];

[activityController setValue:@"Your email Subject" forKey:@"subject"];
[self.viewController presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think everything you did is ok, it just works in this way.

Comment: Do you want to share a local document?

Comment: It is a local document.

Answer (score 0):

is! Simple solution :)  Download and attach file. If you are loading PDF in webview earlier, please find the comment below.

```
    -(void)print:(NSString*)subject withFileName:(NSString*)fileName webFileURL:(NSURL*)webURL{

        if ([UIActivityViewController class]) {

            if (subject) {

                NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
                NSString *title = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];;
                title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",title];

                NSString * filePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",title];

                // Showing spinner
                NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL];
                [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                    // Close the spinner
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Download Error:%@",error.description);
                    }
                    if (data) {
                        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {

                            /* Set this available field on the activity controller */
                            NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];

                            if (data) {
                                [items addObject:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
                            } 

                            // Print webView
                            // {
                            //     [items addObject:[self.webViewInstance viewPrintFormatter]];
                            // }

                            if (webURL) {
                                [items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",subject, [webURL absoluteString]];
                            }

                            UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];

                            [activityViewController setValue:subject forKey:@"subject"]; // Set the mail subject.

                             // If you are not handle it. It will crash in iPad 
                            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
                                activityViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
                                UIPopoverPresentationController *popPC = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController;
                                popPC.sourceView = self.view;
                                popPC.sourceRect = kSharePopArea;
                                popPC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
                            }
                            [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
                        });
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }

        NSString *content = @"write text here";

        NSError* lError;
        NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
        if ([NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways error:&lError]) // Local file
        {
            [items addObject:fileUrl];
        }

        if(content) {
             [items addObject:content];
        }

         if(imagename && [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"]) {
             [items addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"]];
        }


        UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];

        // Add email subject.
        [activityViewController setValue:@"Your email Subject" forKey:@"subject"];


        // If you are not handle it. It will crash in iPad 
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            activityViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
            UIPopoverPresentationController *popPC = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController;
            popPC.sourceView = self.view;
            popPC.sourceRect = kSharePopArea;
            popPC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
        }


        [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: It is a local document, I don't need to download it.